# Button text not centered when textSize exceeds maxHeight

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to vertically center some text within a button, but when the textSize exceeds the height of the button, the text aligns to the top as if android:gravity="top" instead of android:gravity="center"

I've improved the results slightly by adding android:includeFontPadding="false" and android:paddingTop="0dp", but the text is not centered. I'm expecting the text to be vertically centered and therefore clipped above and below the button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:maxHeight="40dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textSize="60dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot of the layout...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8USPa.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing maxHeight?

The problem within your layout is that your text is bigger than the 40dp, but 40dp is the maxHeight.
So wrap content will only go as far as 40dp.

Comment: The question asks that the text be clipped, just on the top and bottom, and not bottom alone.

Comment: True that. I think the negative margin would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try a negative padding or margin to shift the text up.

Comment: Adding a positive or negative top margin does not alter the position of the text at all. Is there another setting that is conflicting/negating this effect? Something to note, the end user will be deciding the height of the button and the height of the text, so for this solution to work I'd need a formula the deduce the negative margin value from the button height and text height values

Comment: This may be a limitation in android then (albeit perhaps intentional). A possible solution could be to make two empty blocks that overlay the text but are inside the button to cut off the characters. One for the top margin and one for the bottom margin, and set the margin and padding to 0 for the button. Then the blocks could just have a size based on some % of the button height.